# Adding fuzziness to a query

Tags: lucene, fuzzy-search

Is there a simple way to add a fuzziness level to a user entered search query in Lucene?

I'd like to avoid having to parse their entered text if possible.

At present if they enter `green boxes` I use a multifield query parser with boosts which easily generates the following for example:

```
+(title:green^10 title:boxes^10) +(category:green^3 category:boxes^3)
```

What I'd like to then do is convert this to:

```
+(title:green^10~0.7 title:boxes^10~0.7) +(category:green^3~0.7 category:boxes^3~0.7)
```

It looks like I'd need to parse the query and add the fuzziness to each term but I was wondering if maybe there's a simple way to add the fuzziness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to subclass and override [MultiFieldQueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/MultiFieldQueryParser.html).getFieldQuery, having it call getFuzzyQuery.